# What does the coin used by the Faceless Men look like?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

I wanted to know if the books (I did not read them) ever described what the coin used by the Faceless Men looked like? In the episodes we do not really see the coin, but I saw lot of reproductions of the coin on the internet, on tattoos, etc.

Answer (score 23):

The coin is described below, from that quote we have the following information:

- It's made of iron
- No larger than a penny in size (penny here referring to a penny in Westeros)
- Rusted along the rim
- One side had writing on it, likely Valyrian (because *Valar Morghulis* is a Valyrian phrase)
- The other side had a man's head on it but was worn down

> Sometimes she wished she had gone off across the narrow sea with Jaqen H'ghar. She still had the stupid coin he'd given her, a piece of iron no larger than a penny and rusted along the rim. One side had writing on it, queer words she could not read. The other showed a man's head, but so worn that all his features had rubbed off. He said it was of great value, but that was probably a lie too, like his name and even his face. That made her so angry that she threw the coin away, but after an hour she got to feeling bad and went and found it again, even though it wasn't worth anything.
>
> <sup>A Clash of Kings, Arya X</sup>

---

[Shire Post Mint](https://www.shirepost.com/collections/a-game-of-thrones-coins) are:

> Officially licensed by George R. R. Martin, these coins come straight from the pockets of Westerosi kings and commoners.

Therefore, showing what their version of the coin looks like is a good idea. They have it on their website as [Iron Coin of the Faceless Man](https://www.shirepost.com/collections/a-game-of-thrones-coins/products/faceless-man), the description for this coin states:

> This is the coin given to Arya Stark by the mysterious assassin Jaqen H'ghar.

[image: Iron Coin of the Faceless Man - Shire Post Mint]
<sup><sub>*Click image to embiggen.*</sub></sup>

From this image we can clearly see that the writing on the coin is:

> Valar morghulis
>
> Valar dohaeris

---

It can be seen clearly in these two images taken from the show as well:

[image: Arya with the coin] [image: Arya buys passage to Braavos]
<sup><sub>*Click images to embiggen.*</sub></sup>

Comment: Why do you say "likely Valyrian", isn't it just as likely yo be Braavosi or some other language spoken in and around the Free Cities?

Comment: Well, not "worn down" so much as "faceless", right?

Comment: What does "penny" mean here? Is it referring to an in-universe coin, the American coin, the British coin or something else?

Comment: @Laurel If it's an American penny, then the coin in the pictures is ridiculously huge.

Comment: @jpmc26 one must remember that the show and the books are different canons, so while in the books it may be penny sized (American penny) the show may have shown it as larger for demonstrative purposes. However, the one in the books does not _need_ to be American/British penny sized, as the lowest denomination in-universe are also called pennies (bronze pennies most often).

Comment: @Paul “likely Valyrian” because the words the Faceless Men used were Valyrian (_Valar Morghulis_ etc.) and the coin likely had those written on them.

Comment: @Laurel, yeah, right I was thinking the same thing.  "Penny"??  GOT coins are called "silvers" and "dragons".

Comment: @JoeC There are pennies in Westeros. Post Conquest, Silver coins are Stags, Gold ones are dragons whereas copper ones are Stars, Groats, Halfgroats, Pennies and Half pennies (Value descending in that order).

Comment: @Paul It's not a regular Braavosi coin, that's for sure. The sailor Arya uses to get to Braavos reacts in such a way that he knows it's a coin of the Faceless men specifically. This wouldn't happen with a regular coin.

Answer (score 5):

As a fan of the TV Show, I'd just like to complete @TheLethalCarrot's answer. Seems that not only the TV show coin is different from the [description in the books](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/190350/28528) as well as [the officially George-R-R-Martin-approved  coin](https://www.shirepost.com/collections/a-game-of-thrones-coins/products/faceless-man), but it also seems that they used at least three different coins in different seasons! Look at the screenshots:

S02E10:

[image]

S03E10:

[image]

S04E10:

[image]

[image]

SE502:

[image]

[image]

[image]

5x03:

[image]

Seems like we fans take much more care about how the coin looked like than the TV producers :-) Might be a bit disappointing, but that's many times the case. So we should let our fantasy paint the picture :)

PS: The coins from Seasons 4 and 5 are definitely not just iron.

PS: the one from Season 4 was what stuck in my memory, probably as it is the most mysterious one :)

Comment: Maybe the coin is magical, just like faceless people faces.

Comment: You think the TV producers should just _re-use_ a prop, when the honest workers of the Propmakers Union have the right to make a nice fresh one each season?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Are you suggesting that the motivation is purely to prop up their pay checks?

Comment: @PeterM that is a slur on the fine Associated Imitation Coinmakers of Hollywood/Ireland. They famously work for free.